# IntelliJ Plugin: Duplicate all the command line output to file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, logging, intellij-plugin

I want to write a Jetbrains IntelliJ plugin which aims to duplicate all the command line output to some files with timestamp. Directly change the direction of `System.out` when coding is not I want, and the recording is executed passively by the plugin, so it's just a duplicate of command line information. Thus, how can I implement it?

For example, `File_7891242885.log` records "Hello World!" and other command line output when I executed the class at timestamp 7891242885.

Comment: Interesting idea. What is the question exactly?

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how to implement it, since it not just redirect the output stream...

Comment: I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development to discuss it with the IDEA team directly.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov Thanks very much for your advice! I have posted my question to the forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by the suggestion from @Karol Lewandowski.
[Suggestion from Karol Lewandowski](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQNas.png)